# Is multiple level Highchart Drilldown possible in adjacent charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am a newbie in highchart. I have few queries in drilldown.

In drilldown same chart gets replaced. Can we give particular space for drilled new chart (if I say new div)? How can I add more levels of drilldown in different chart ?

By default if you have more series in the legend, clicking on one of them will add/remove that series. Can we make the series still visible a append a new chart ?

Answer (score 9):

have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/6LXVQ/97/ for a 3 level example

```
    series: [{
        id: 'toplevel',
        name: 'Animals',
        data: [
            {name: 'Cats', y: 4, drilldown: 'level1'},
            {name: 'Dogs', y: 2},
            {name: 'Cows', y: 1},
            {name: 'Sheep',y: 2},
            {name: 'Pigs', y: 1}
        ]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [ { 
            id:'level1',
            name: 'Level 1',
            data: [
                {name: 'Trees', y: 1},
                {name: 'Plants', y: 2},
                {name: 'Grass', y: 3},
                {name: 'Deeper', y: 4, drilldown: 'level2'}
            ] 
        },{                
            id:'level2',
            name: 'Level 2',
            data: [
                {name: 'Green', y:1},
                {name: 'Red', y:2},
                {name: 'Blue', y:3},
                {name: 'Deeper', y: 4, drilldown: 'level3'}
            ] 
        },{
            id: 'level3',
            name: 'Level 3',
            data: [
                {name:'Yes', y:1},
                {name:'it',y:2},
                {name:'works', y:3}
            ]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: clean answer. Thanks..!

Answer (score 4):

At this moment 2 / 3 levels are available. See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6LXVQ/1/

```
series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            name: 'Animals',
            data: [
                {name: 'Cats', 
                 y: 4,
                 drilldown: 'cats'},
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {

            id:'cats',
            data: [1,2,3] 
        }]
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to get new chart instead of same chart getting replaced on each levels?

Comment: Always you can destroy chart and create new one.

Comment: Lack of knowledge in javascript is creating problem for me :( Is there any other way through which On click of item in chart 1 new chart opens (functionality same as in drilldown) ?

Comment: With the same options or another? Any back button should be dispalyed to back for "started" chart

Comment: any other option exists other than drilldown? I don't want any backbutton. I want both the charts to be displayed at same time

Comment: So catch click event on the point, then destroy chart and create new one.