# Does anyone have idea how to implement the dynamic dril down charts for three or four levels using highchart API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

How to implement the dynamic dril down charts for three or four or n levels using highchart API as it
 can be drilled down by two levels only.please see below sample code which I have been trying to implement:

Comment: [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182865/is-multiple-level-highchart-drilldown-possible-in-adjacent-charts). Check out the fiddle in first answer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153403/drilldown-multiple-levels-highchart) one too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to `drilldown` asynchronously as shown in Highcharts [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/) from [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown).

If each point will have `drilldown` enabled, and a new series will be able to be found and added as a drilldown series, then muliple levels should't be a problem.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jaydkfgv/

Drill into first points 3 times - 3 levels.